# Activity doesn't save the value when i change the orientation

Tags: android, kotlin

I try to write the programm tha generates random lognormal value with given mean and variance value. I wrote a program and i overrided the onSaveInstanceState function to save my value and then onRestoreInstanceState to restore the value when the orientation of the phone is changed but when i try to do it the generated value changes to 0.
That's my MainActivity.kt:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var randomValue: Double = 0.0
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val mean = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.mean_val)
        val vari = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.variance_value)
        val bttn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.get_random_num)
        val textv = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.random_number_result)
        bttn.setOnClickListener {
            val mean_val = mean.text.toString().toDouble()
            val std_dev = vari.text.toString().toDouble()

            randomValue = generatedLogNormalRandom(mean_val, std_dev)
            textv.text = randomValue.toString()
        }
    }



    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
        val userNumber: Double = randomValue
        outState.putDouble("randomValue", userNumber)
    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
        persistentState: PersistableBundle?
    ) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        val userDouble: Double = savedInstanceState!!.getDouble("randomValue")
        randomValue = userDouble
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.random_number_result).text = randomValue.toString()
    }

    private fun generatedLogNormalRandom(meanVal: Double, stdDev: Double): Double {
        val normalMean = ln(meanVal.pow(2) / sqrt(stdDev.pow(2) + meanVal.pow(2)))
        val normalStdDev = sqrt(ln(1 + (stdDev.pow(2) / meanVal.pow(2))))

        val z = Random().nextGaussian()
        return exp(normalMean + normalStdDev * z)
    }
}
```

I tried to do it without onRestoreInstanceState method just using

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            randomValue = savedInstanceState.getDouble("randomValue")
            textv.text = randomValue.toString()
        }
```

but it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use ViewModel, because the main purpose of ViewModel is to hold data in case of configuration change.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

How to use ViewModel?

dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
```

class:

```
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class CounterViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var count = 0

    fun getCount(): Int {
        return count
    }

    fun incrementCount() {
        count++
    }
}
```

Inside your activity or fragment:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val counterViewModel: CounterViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        displayCount()

        buttonIncrement.setOnClickListener {
            counterViewModel.incrementCount()
            displayCount()
        }
    }

    private fun displayCount() {
        val count = counterViewModel.getCount()
        textViewCount.text = count.toString()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just changed

```
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    val userNumber: Double = randomValue
    outState.putDouble("randomValue", userNumber)
    outState.putString("meanValue", findViewById<EditText>(R.id.mean_val).text.toString())
    outState.putString("varianceValue", findViewById<EditText>(R.id.variance_value).text.toString())
}

override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
    val userDouble: Double = savedInstanceState.getDouble("randomValue")
    randomValue = userDouble
    findViewById<TextView>(R.id.random_number_result).text = randomValue.toString()

    val meanVal = savedInstanceState.getString("meanValue")
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.mean_val).setText(meanVal)

    val varianceVal = savedInstanceState.getString("varianceValue")
    findViewById<EditText>(R.id.variance_value).setText(varianceVal)
}
```